# *.do in struts 1.2

Tags: java, struts

I think I know Struts 1.2 very well, but still I am confused about the `*.do` pattern.
Can you please explain the simple meaning of the pattern `*.do`? And why it is only `*.do`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bad english is not a problem, but "u" instead of "you" and "plz" instead of "please" is just plain laziness.

Comment: @Joachim .. Thank you very much for indicating my mistake... Because i really like that someone show my mistake to me. I keep it in my mind .. Thanks again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a URL mapping of the struts action Servlet as shown below (copied from [struts doc](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/configuration.html)). It can be anything you want. *.do is the default mapping I believe.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

`*.do` is mentioned in the Struts documentation and has become the defacto standard. But you can choose anything you like. Another common pattern is `/do/*`.